# Suggestion for best normaizilation process in a big set of screeing data

Tags: r, statistics, expression

I have a data set that has positive and negative control and a set gene expression. I want to check which gene was significantly expressed in that data set. Therefore, My question is what statistical procedure would be best in my situation? please help me. Thanks! Biswajit

data structure
[head of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42K6s.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yo can use Limma, Deseq and EdgeR packages in R. You can check [here](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/edgeR/inst/doc/edgeRUsersGuide.pdf),[here](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/limma/inst/doc/usersguide.pdf) and [here](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/DESeq2/inst/doc/DESeq2.html)